# terraform provider plugin symlink creation to plugin fails in Unix

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

1. OS: Unix
2. .terraform.rc file content: plugin_cache_dir = "$HOME/.terraform.d/plugin-cache"
3. I have placed aws provider plugin to "$HOME/.terraform.d/plugin-cache". So, when I run "terraform init", it copies plugin from above plugin_cache_dir to current directory under .terrform directory. Plugin size is around 240MB for aws version 4.13. This helps to skip download each time running "terraform init". content of "$HOME/.terraform.d/plugin-cache" as below.

[root@localhost plugin-cache]# ls -lrt
total 224972
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 230371328 May  5 15:51 terraform-provider-aws_v4.13.0_x5
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root        23 May  7 22:22 registry.terraform.io

Issue: I ran command "TF_LOG=TRACE terraform init" and I see that it fails to create symlink to plugin file for aws provider. See below snippet from output as root cause. How do I fix so it creates symlink instead of doing local copy from above "plugin_cache_dir" to current init directory?

2022-05-12T10:36:49.601-0400 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: scanning directory .terraform/providers
2022-05-12T10:36:49.601-0400 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: failed to resolve symlinks for .terraform/providers: lstat .terraform: no such file or directory
2022-05-12T10:36:49.601-0400 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: error while scanning directory .terraform/providers: cannot search .terraform/providers: lstat .terraform/providers: no such file or directory
2022-05-12T10:36:49.601-0400 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: scanning directory /root/.terraform.d/plugin-cache
2022-05-12T10:36:49.601-0400 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: found registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.13.0 for linux_amd64 at /root/.terraform.d/plugin-cache/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/4.13.0/linux_amd64
2022-05-12T10:36:49.601-0400 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: including /root/.terraform.d/plugin-cache/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/4.13.0/linux_amd64 as a candidate package for registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws 4.13.0

Answer (score 0):

Terraform's behavior for the local cache directory is to try to create a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) from the local `.terraform` directory to the cache, but to fall back on creating a full copy of the symbolic link fails for any reason.

Some reasons the symbolic link could fail include:

- You are on a Unix system but you are using a non-Unix filesystem which cannot store symbolic links.
- You are on a Windows Vista or later system and your administrator hasn't granted you access to create symbolic links.

  (You would need [the "Create Symbolic Link" privilege](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/create-symbolic-links) As the Microsoft documentation suggests, legacy Windows applications often don't handle symbolic links well and so administrators will often not grant that permission to avoid poor interactions with that legacy software. Terraform itself correctly handles symbolic links, though.)

If either of the above situations are true, Terraform will be forced to create a copy instead of a symbolic link.

Someone reported in that GitHub issue that enabling "Developer Mode" in is one way to get permission to create symbolic links on a Windows 10 or later system, although I don't routinely use Windows so I cannot confirm that myself.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation Martin. So neither of above applies to me, though I am trying to solve this on windows 10 as well but for now lets keep it for Unix. I am using CentOS7 in virtual box. I am not using Non-Unix file system. I am doing terraform init right under root user home. Check below output for reference. Still any idea for a fix is appreciated.

Comment: [root@localhost terraform]# pwd
/root/terraform
[root@localhost terraform]# ls -a
.  ..  main.tf  .terraform  .terraform.lock.hcl
[root@localhost terraform]# du -sh .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/4.13.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v4.13.0_x5
254M    .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/4.13.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v4.13.0_x5
[root@localhost terraform]# cat ../.terraform.rc
plugin_cache_dir = "$HOME/.terraform.d/plugin-cache"

Comment: I just ran below command and still copied aws plugin of sizwe 245MB into local .terraform directory.
[root@localhost terraform]# terraform init -plugin-dir=$HOME/.terraform.d/plugin-cache
[root@localhost .terraform]# du -sh providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/4.13.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v4.13.0_x5
254M    providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/4.13.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v4.13.0_x5

Comment: I imagine there are some other reasons that creating a symlink could fail which I didn't consider when I wrote my comment. Perhaps running `TF_LOG=trace terraform init` will produce some extra logging which explains what Terraform was doing. If you learn something new by trying that, please edit your question to include it because it's hard to read terminal output all packed onto one line in comments.

Comment: Martin, greatly appreciate your help here. Found the root cause doing "TF_LOG=trace terraform init" and I have updated my question limited to failure of symlink creation with output from command. I am not still not clear what cli config is missing to fix this for provider.

Comment: Maybe it would be informative to try creating a similar symlink manually and see if it succeeds. If not, the error message might explain why not: `mkdir -p .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/4.13.0` followed by `ln -s /root/.terraform.d/plugin-cache/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/4.13.0/linux_amd64 .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/4.13.0/linux_amd64`